# MacOS Ventura freeze/crash when i plug in my Arduino Nano Clone

Tags: macos, arduino

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2013 Late with OpenCore Patcher. Currently Ventura 13.3.1 is installed. Before this version was installed, i had no problem using arduino on my MacOS computer. But right now, when i plug in my Arduino Nano Clone, the computer suddenly freezes and does not respond to any interaction. I have to press and hold the power button to restart the computer.

I tried to plug in another board called NodeMCU which has CH340 chip likewise i did with the arduino, same trouble happened again. So at that point i was guessing it was a CH340 driver problem or something about it. To test my theory, i plugged in my Raspberry Pi Pico and it worked perfectly. So it's probably CH340 chip problem but i could not find any solution in web. May there is a system integrity problem with OpenCore which the version is not compatible with the current operation system version.

If anyone can help me with this issue i'd be really appreciated, since i have a project which must be completed within 3 weeks.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you clone your setup before the update? …or at least have a Time Machine backup? You're flying in unchartered space, meaning if something goes wrong, you have to be able to revert to 'last known good' to re-test.

Comment: Did you install Arduino IDE, add any required drivers and set it up?  I plug various Arduino boards into my Windows 10 ThinkPad with Arduino IDE up and running.